# Aggregate Function alias from select used in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Where is the error here:

```
SELECT Users.UserID, 
   ClassCourses.CourseID,
   ClassCourses.MinMark,
   sum(StudentMark) as SMark    
FROM   Users 
INNER JOIN UserExams ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID
INNER JOIN Exams ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
where  ClassCourses.MinMark> SMark
group by Users.UserID, ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MinMark
```

I got an error:

> Invalid column name 'SMark'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use column aliases in your WHERE clause. Also, when comparing results of aggregations, you must use the HAVING clause, after the GROUP BY is applied.

Do something like this:

```
SELECT Users.UserID, 
    ClassCourses.CourseID,
    ClassCourses.MinMark,
    sum(StudentMark) as SMark    
FROM   Users 
INNER JOIN UserExams ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID
INNER JOIN Exams ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID
GROUP BY Users.UserID, ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MinMark
HAVING ClassCourses.MinMark > sum(StudentMark)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the alias in the `WHERE` clause, because the `WHERE` statement is *logically* executed before the `SELECT`, so it doesn't see that name `SMark`.

You can put it in a subquery instead, and filter in the outer one like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      Users.UserID, 
      ClassCourses.CourseID,
      ClassCourses.MinMark,
      sum(StudentMark) as SMark    
    FROM   Users 
    INNER JOIN UserExams     ON Users.UserID     = UserExams.UserID
    INNER JOIN Exams         ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
    INNER JOIN ClassCourses  ON Exams.ClassID    = ClassCourses.ClassID
                            AND Exams.CourseID   = ClassCourses.CourseID
    group by Users.UserID, 
             ClassCourses.CourseID,
             ClassCourses.MinMark
) AS t
where  MinMark> SMark
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    (

    SELECT Users.UserID, 
       ClassCourses.CourseID,
       ClassCourses.MinMark,
       sum(StudentMark) as SMark    
    FROM   Users 
    INNER JOIN UserExams ON Users.UserID = UserExams.UserID
    INNER JOIN Exams ON UserExams.ExamID = Exams.ExamID 
    INNER JOIN ClassCourses ON Exams.ClassID = ClassCourses.ClassID AND Exams.CourseID = ClassCourses.CourseID

    group by Users.UserID, ClassCourses.CourseID,ClassCourses.MinMark
    )a
where  MinMark > SMark
```